# cmake can't find files unless I give it the exact path

Tags: boost, cmake

OK, I'm playing with boost and want openCL. Downloaded the package and am here :

```
 /root/boost_1_63_0/libs/compute
```

When I do a "cmake ." it tells me it can't find openCL.

```
[root@172-1-8-3 compute]# cmake . -DOpenCL_INCPATH=/opt/nvidia/cuda/include
DEBUG OpenCL_INCPATH=/opt/nvidia/cuda/include
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenCL (missing: OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/opencl/FindOpenCL.cmake:76 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

I added the debug line to be sure my variable was actually getting set.
I can add the path to the line

```
FIND_PATH(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS CL/cl.h PATHS  "$ENV{CUDADIR}/include" ${_OpenCL_INC_CAND} "/usr/local/cuda/include" "/opt/cuda/include" "/opt/AMDAPP/include" ENV OpenCL_INCPATH)
```

If I add it "/opt/nvidia/cuda/include" after PATHS, then it happily finds OpenCL. But, surely it's supposed to find it from the "ENV ..." bit. If I need to hack source with the exact locations of things, then I may as well not have a build tool.

I tried it with/without the terminating / on the path. I know I'm probably not supposed to be doing this here, but it seems like if I can get this to work, then the normal build will work properly. I actually want to do this to build cpp-ethereum with GPU support.

What am I missing??

Comment: `ENV` refers to **environment variable**, as opposite to *CMake variable*. By using `cmake -DOpenCL_INCPATH=<...>` you set CMake variable. Instead, set environment one: `OpenCL_INCPATH=<...> cmake .`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually specify the include dir from the command line, then all you need to do is pass the

```
-DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/nvidia/cuda/include
```

argument to cmake on the command line.  This will override the result of find_path.

If you are trying to make CMake read an environment variable, the syntax for that is

```
$ENV{NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}
```